# How to output the content of JavaMapwithStateDstream to the textFile?

Tags: apache-spark, real-time, spark-streaming

all. I have two questions about Spark-streaming's application.

First one is how to output JavaMapwithStateDstream's content into the textFile, I went through the API document, and found out it's of the Dstreamlike interface.So I use the following code, trying to output the content：

```
Function3<String, Optional<Integer>, State<Integer>, Tuple2<String, Integer>> mappingFunc =
            new Function3<String, Optional<Integer>, State<Integer>, Tuple2<String, Integer>>() {
              @Override
              public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String word, Optional<Integer> one,
                  State<Integer> state) {
                int sum =  one.or(0) + (state.exists() ? state.get() : 0);
                Tuple2<String, Integer> output = new Tuple2<>(word, sum);
                state.update(sum);
                return output;
              }
            };

   JavaMapWithStateDStream<String, Integer, Integer, Tuple2<String, Integer>> stateDstream =
           adCounts.mapWithState(StateSpec.function(mappingFunc));

    stateDstream.print();
    stateDstream.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<Tuple2<String,Integer>>, Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call(JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, Integer>> rdd) throws Exception {
            rdd.saveAsTextFile("/path/to/hdfs");
            return null;
        }
    });
```

However, Nothing output to the hdfs path.But I can see the print result from the console

[image]

Please tell me what's the matter??How can I output the content of JavaMapwithStateDstream?

Second question:

I want to update the real-time result every duration, even no other new flowing in, how can I implement it??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the reason why JavaMapwithStateDstream can print out something but not saving the textFile, since it is updated/initialized every duration, new data flowing in will be covered by next time's initialization, thus nothing can be saved into the textFile.

Workaround is to declare a new variable to copy the value of stateDstream,
I use Dstream here, I think JavaPairDstream should be also ok.

```
DStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> fin_Counts = stateDstream.dstream();
fin_Counts.print();
```

fin_Counts can be updated and saved.